# how to create underline in the PreferenceCategory for separating EditTextPreference

Tags: java, android, xml, preferencescreen, edittextpreference

i need the Underline after every EditTextPreference UI for the separating it .

**Code**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi4G0.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idbVq.png)

adding Image for better understanding
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fOpY.png)

i have create layout .xml style and to  EditTextPreference  or PreferenceScreen but it's did not worked . i also try to add from java side but it did not worked for me

Comment: Hi there please submit your source code as the plain text format